# Can a formatter in an R formattable context be created so that it is conditionally applied?

Tags: r, conditional-formatting, formatter, formattable

I have a dataframe that will be formatted using the R formattable library.  I created a formatter to apply the appropriate formatting.  However, the dataframe contains some NAs and when they are encountered the formatting fails. What I really would like to do is code the formatter so that it conditionally determines when to apply the format and when not to. The code below illustrates the issue.

```
library(formattable)

theData1 <- data.frame("A"=c(12.1456, 143.012), "B"=c(145.23435, 331.22335))
theData2 <- data.frame("A"=c(12.1456, 143.012), "B"=c(145.23435, 331.22335), "C"=c(143.012, NA))

MyFormatter <- formattable::formatter(
   "span", style = ~ style(font.weight="bold"), x ~ style(round(x,2)))

tbl1 <- formattable::formattable(theData1, list('A'=MyFormatter, 'B'=MyFormatter))
tbl2 <- formattable::formattable(theData1, list('A'=MyFormatter, 'B'=MyFormatter, 'C'=MyFormatter))
```

A statement: `formattable(tbl2)` errors out with the error "Error in .mapply(function(name, value) {:
zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length"

How can I code the segment `x ~ style(round(x,2))` so that it is ignored when x is NA?

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` can be used to handle `NA`s

```
MyFormatter <- formattable::formatter(
   "span", 
   style = ~ style(font.weight = "bold"),
   x ~ style(ifelse(!is.na(x), round(x, 2), ""))
)

formattable::formattable(theData2, list('A'=MyFormatter, 'B'=MyFormatter, 'C'=MyFormatter))
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had thought I tried 'ifelse' since that is a function I do use a lot, but I may have placed it in the wrong location of the code. Anyway, thanks ... this works.